# RecyclerView Attempt to invoke virtual method setAdapter on null object reference

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a `BaseActivity` that holds code that is common among different activities. I have multiple activites that extend `BaseActivity`. One of the common is a menu button that opens a `MaterialDialog` with a list of printers that the user can connect to. The list is held in a `RecyclerView`. When I try to `setAdapter()` in `BaseActivity` I get the following error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setAdapter(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter)' on a null object reference
```

If I don't `setAdapter()` the dialog opens just fine. What am I doing wrong?

Error output

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setAdapter(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter)' on a null object reference
    at com.app.nex.nex.BaseActivity.onSelectPrinter(BaseActivity.java:445)
    at com.app.nex.nex.BaseActivity$1.onItemClick(BaseActivity.java:206)
    at com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.DrawerBuilder$6.onClick(DrawerBuilder.java:1786)
    at com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.DrawerBuilder$6.onClick(DrawerBuilder.java:1760)
    at com.mikepenz.fastadapter.FastAdapter$1.onClick(FastAdapter.java:608)
    at com.mikepenz.fastadapter.utils.EventHookUtil$1.onClick(EventHookUtil.java:72)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6306)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:23962)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6823)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1557)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1445)
```

BaseActivity

```
private ArrayList<String> mPrinters = new ArrayList<>();
private AccountHeader headerResult = null;
private Drawer result = null;


@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    context = this;
    this.savedInstanceState = savedInstanceState;

    //Setup DrawerBuilder that has the SetupPrinter button that calls onSelectPrinter()

    new DrawerBuilder().withActivity(this).build();

    headerResult = new AccountHeaderBuilder()
            .withActivity(this)
            .withCompactStyle(true)
            .withHeaderBackground(R.drawable.logo)
            .withSavedInstance(savedInstanceState)
            .build();


    result = new DrawerBuilder()
            .withActivity(this)
            .withAccountHeader(headerResult) 
            .addDrawerItems(
                    new SectionDrawerItem().withName(R.string.side_menu_title_settings),
                    new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.side_menu_0_printer).withIcon(R.drawable.fire_smoke).withIdentifier(R.integer.side_menu_0_printer),
                    new SectionDrawerItem().withName("Settings"),
                    new SecondaryDrawerItem().withName("tWO").withIcon(R.drawable.fire)
            )
            .withOnDrawerItemClickListener(new Drawer.OnDrawerItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onItemClick(View view, int position, IDrawerItem drawerItem) {
                    int item = (int) drawerItem.getIdentifier();
                    switch (item) {
                        case R.integer.side_menu_0_printer:
                            onSelectPrinter();
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                    System.out.println("DRAWER " + drawerItem.getIdentifier());
                    if (drawerItem != null && drawerItem.getIdentifier() == 1) {
                        //startSupportActionMode(new ActionBarCallBack());
                    }

                    if (drawerItem instanceof Nameable) {

                    }

                    return false;
                }
            })
            .withSavedInstance(savedInstanceState)
            .build();

}


protected void onSelectPrinter() {

        mPrinters.add("Epson 123");
        mPrinters.add("Canon 999");
        mPrinters.add("HP 12322");
        mPrinters.add("Brother 12344");

        TestAdapter adapter = new TestAdapter(mPrinters, this);

        MaterialDialog dialog =
                new MaterialDialog.Builder(this)
                        .title(R.string.title_printer_setup)
                        .customView(R.layout.dialog_select_printer, true)
                        .negativeText(android.R.string.cancel)
                        .build();

        RecyclerView rv = dialog.getRecyclerView();
        rv.setAdapter(adapter);
        dialog.show();
}
```

TestAdapter

```
public class TestAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TestAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private final String TAG = this.getClass().getSimpleName();

    private ArrayList<String> mPrinters;
    private Context mContext;

    public TestAdapter(ArrayList<String> printers, Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        mPrinters = printers;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.dialog_select_printer, parent, false);
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(view);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onviewbindholder called");

        holder.tvTxt.setText(mPrinters.get(position));
        holder.rlLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mPrinters.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView tvTxt;
        RelativeLayout rlLayout;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            rlLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.layoutSelectPrinter);
            tvTxt = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvPrinterName);
        }
    }
}
```

rv_select_printer.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#80000000"
        android:id="@+id/tvPrinterName"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

dialog_select_printer.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/layoutSelectPrinter"
    >

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvPrinters"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: would you mind passing all your code of onSelectPrinter() in your switch case,I think it still will give the same result,I would advise to create the adapter outside you switch case

Comment: Where should I create the adapter? In `onCreate` ?

Answer (score 0):

use this in onSelectPrinter() method :

```
LayoutInflater inflater=LayoutInflater.from(getBaseContext());
View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_select_printer,null);
MaterialDialog dialog =
                new MaterialDialog.Builder(this)
                        .title(R.string.title_printer_setup)
                        .setView(view)
                        .negativeText(android.R.string.cancel)
                        .build();
RecyclerView rv = view.findViewById(R.id.rvPrinters);
rv.setAdapter(adapter);
dialog.show();
```